# Сheck object fields for data matching to specified conditions on native javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have no experience in javascript. And the best way to solve this problem is not clear to me.
I have native javascript,
I have an object and I need to check the fields of the object for compliance with the given conditions.

I immediately made a simple option using "IF"

But I think this is a very bad decision. How can this be done better?

```
    let user = {
    name: 'test',
    nickname: 'Doe',
    age: 25,
    skills: {
        skill1: 'go',
        skill2: 'php',
        skill3: 'best of the best'
    }
};
let checkField = (obj) => {
    if (
        typeof (obj.name) === 'string' &&
        typeof (obj.nickname) === 'string' &&
        obj.age >= 16 && obj.age <= 50 &&
        Object.keys(obj).length > 0
    ) {
        console.log('true')
    } else {
        console.log('false')
    }
};
checkField(user);
```

Сonditions

```
let user = {
    name: 'test',   == string
    nickname: 'Doe', == string
    age: 25,  number in range 16..50
    skills: { not empty object
        skill1: 'go',  == string
        skill2: 'php',  == string
        skill3: 'best of the best'  == string
    }
};
```

Comment: You can also ask this question on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ as they mainly review code and give you suggestions on how to improve your code.

Comment: You could make another object that defines the validations, and have a generic method to "run" them, but that said I think the only issue with your current approach is that you're checking `Object.keys(obj)` instead of `Object.keys(obj.skills)`.

Comment: I think everything is okay except, `obj && Object.keys(obj).length > 0 && ...` should be checked at the first.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with what you're trying to do, although you are missing a couple of things according to the conditions given -

1. A check for type of `age` to be `number` and
2. `obj.skills` instead of `obj` to check if it is not empty.

Here would be the complete corrected code according to the conditions -

```js
 let user = {
    name: 'test',
    nickname: 'Doe',
    age: 25,
    skills: {
        skill1: 'go',
        skill2: 'php',
        skill3: 'best of the best'
    }
};
let checkField = (obj) => {
    if (
        typeof obj.name === 'string' &&
        typeof obj.nickname === 'string' &&
        typeof obj.age === 'number' &&
        obj.age >= 16 && obj.age <= 50 &&
        obj.skills && Object.keys(obj.skills).length > 0
    ) {
        console.log('true')
    } else {
        console.log('false')
    }
};
checkField(user);
```

In addition, if you'd also like to check that each property of `skills` is of type `string`, you can iterate over the object and check it like -

```
Object.keys(obj.skills).every(x => typeof(obj.skills[x])==='string')
```

Here's a [documentation to Array.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

Comment: Thanks for you solution!

Answer (score 0):

i would say that it may be worthwhile to explore a validation library / module like hapi's joi. here's an example of how you might be able to extract all of the things wrong with it. for example append the following code to the input in this link: https://npm.runkit.com/@hapi/joi

```
const schema = Joi.object().keys({
  name: Joi.string(),
  nickname: Joi.string(),
  age: Joi.number(),
  skills: Joi.object().min(1)
})
console.log(schema.validate({
    name: 'test',
    nickname: 'Doe',
    age: 25,
    skills: {
        skill3: 'best of the best'
    }
}))
console.log(schema.validate({
    name: 'test',
    nickname: 'Doe',
    age: 25,
    skills: {
    }
}))
```

you can find the full api docs here: https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md

Comment: Thanks, looks good, but for my solution need native js.  Maybe I will use this library in the future!